# How can I compute monthly payments buy using this formula?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Payment=(Rate*(1+Rate)^N)/(((1+Rate)^N)-1))

I was told to "Write a Python module (loan.py) that assigns values to Loan Amount, Monthly Interest Rate and Number
of payments, using the above formula, computes the monthly payment."

For example:"if Loan amount is $10000, Monthly Interest Rate is 0.01 (or 12% annual interest rate), the
number of payments is 36, Monthly payment should be $332.14.Verify that your program works
correctly by using this data as input."

I've tried using the following code but I'm being told that I'm "dividing a float by 0".

```
l=eval(input("What's the loan amount?"))
l=l*1.0
r=eval(input("What's the monthy interest rate?(as a fraction)"))
r=r*1.0
N=eval(input("What's the number of payments you need to make?")) 
N=N*1.0
P=((r*(1+r)**N)/((1+r**N)-1))*l
print("Your monthly payment amount would be: ",P)
```

If you could tell me what I did wrong, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interest_rate=eval(input("What's the loan amount?"))
loan_amount=interest_rate*1.0

interest_rate=eval(input("What's the monthy interest rate?(as a fraction)"))
interest_rate=interest_rate*1.0

number_of_payments=eval(input("What's the number of payments you need to make?")) 
number_of_payments=number_of_payments*1.0

monthly_payment=((interest_rate*(1+interest_rate)**number_of_payments)/(((1+interest_rate)**number_of_payments)-1))

print("Your monthly payment amount would be: ",monthly_payment*loan_amount)
```

please always try to use meaningful variable names in your code...It will make your programming life easier.